# Convert dynamic XML url to plain HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsonp

I have a script which allows to display Google suggestions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input#searchbox").autocomplete({ 

   source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({

          url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',

          dataType: 'JSONP',

          data: {

            format: 'json',

            q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?hl=nl&output=toolbar&q=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '"'

          },

          success: function(data) {

          if (typeof data == 'string') data = $.parseJSON(data);

              response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {

              return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };


            }));

          }

        });          
   }       

 }); 
});
```

Here is the Fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xbpk7/8/)

The problem is that it has to make a call to yahoo APi which is responding way to slow, sometimes not at all. So is there a way to do the suggestions without the yahoo call?

Comment: Are you sure it's the response from Yahoo that's slow? I tried out the fiddle and the response from Yahoo was usually around 40ms. Most of the delay seems to come from jQuery waiting to send the request in the first place. The default delay for autocomplete is 300ms. Try setting the delay property in the autocomplete options to a lower value.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you should definitely add the following options to your ajax options - cache: true, jsonpCallback: 'somefunctionname'. It doesn't matter what you set for the callback name, that just makes it so the results are cacheable. The results from yahoo for a given query string aren't likely to change often. That way if someone types the same string twice, the results will just load from the cache (until it expires) rather than calling Yahoo again. This will give you another little performance bump.

Comment: One more thing: call toLowerCase() on request.term before the Ajax call. It looks like the Yahoo results are not case-sensitive. So making all the terms lowercase increases the likelihood that results are loaded from the cache versus making another call to Yahoo.